# PHPUnit 9.5+ Random Assertions count?

Tags: testing, count, phpunit, assertion

As shown in the picture below, on consecutive runs (of course with no changes whatsoever, I get different assertions count (and memory usage). As long as they pass I'm happy. But still, out of curiosity I'd like to know what's going on there.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go through my tests one by one and I determined that the described behavior is caused by \Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse::assertJsonStructure (Laravel Testing "helpers") combined with faker data fed to the tests and the loops in the the tests themselves (and not by PHPUnit 9.5)